Bread from bread machine not rising properly
I would like to use my bread makers standard 5h option so I can set it on a timer overnight. Unfortunately this recipe causes the bread to not raise properly.
The 3h "quick" recipe works fine.
Note: I have tried more/less yeast to no effect. I also use ~19g of EV olive oil instead of butter.
Pics here of loaves and recipes
https://imgur.com/a/Br44hyh
Thanks in advance for any tips of how I can improve my loaf on the 5h setting

Does the instruction booklet say to position the ingredients in a particular way when using the timer? Are you doing that?

It does not, unfortunately. Good thinking though

In general, the idea is wet ingredients + salt at the bottom, then dry ingredients, then yeast on top so that it doesn't mix with wet ingredients and become active or die from contact with salt. Have you been doing something similar, or just letting it all mix?

Looks like the bread is over proofed, and has collapsed.  You could experiment by halving the amount of yeast.
